# how to set days "date()" limit for month function in php

Tags: php

How to set days limit for month function in PHP ? `<?php date("t") ?>` for example I want to set 30 days for each month January to December (for every year).

Because I am creating finance software for me and I am giving payment to my clients as per 30 days every month. So, I'm using date picker as start finance date and end finance date. But some of the months having 31 and 29 days in a month. But I want to fix 30 days for each month(for every year). So, How can I fix 30 days for each month?

Comment: Create your own function and use it. Also check http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php

Comment: I'm assuming this is for stuff you're *selling*, since you appear to have control over payment terms - it's hard to tell since the phrase "giving payment to my clients" is incongruous - clients are normally people who pay *you,* not the other way around. Why wouldn't you just bill them for the same amount on the first of the month, ensuring of course the first billing cycle is a partial one just  to get to the start of next month.

Comment: Do not overwrite functions, make your own function, e.g. `my_date` and use that. There is absolutely no reason to overwrite functions.

Comment: Guys problem is not about payment delivery. I can pay 1st date of the month as well. That's the not problem. Problem is that I fixed the finance for clients as 30 days for each month.

Comment: So if I selected date in date picker calendar fields for example 1st Feb to 29 Feb . then my software calculation will be wrong. because on each month, I am getting payment as 30 days calculation. 
so my software will be giving me calculation as 29 days. same like is for other months as well .like in march having 31 days in a month. so in short I want the result as per 30 days if I selected 28,29,30 or 31 days in calendars. But 1st to 27 it should result as per selected days in the calendar. but if I selected end date 28 to 31 date in any month then it should display the result as 30 days.

Comment: ` if(strtotime($start_date) >= date('28/02/2016') ) `
can any body suggest me how can i set condition for dates in if statement .

For example, I want to set the condition
' if( strtotime($end_date)) >= 28days ){

condition true

} '
means 28 to 31days should result as 30 days.